# ValidationMessageFor fires when field is not edited

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm displaying fields on an edit screen. The fields with the issue are from a List of model entities. If I modify all the screen field's values and press submit, there is no issues. But if there are any unmodified fields, the RegularExpression message displays, even though the entry is valid.

It the ValueDesc field that is the issue.

Also, is there a way to allow entering a zero on the Edit screen but not the Add screen?

The same model works fine on my add screen.

Here's some of the code:

```
public class ModLenBinRefModelEntity : IEntityModel
{
    public int AtcId { get; set; }
    public List<LengthBinRefModelEntity> LengthBinReferences { get; set; }

public class LengthBinRefModelEntity : IEntityModel
{
    public short BinId { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bin Number is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Bin Number")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[1-9]\d*", ErrorMessage = "Bin Number must be 1 or greater")]
    public short BinNumber { get; set; }

    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Bin Value Description is required")]
    [Display(Name = "Value Description")]
    [DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:N1}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[1-9]\d*", ErrorMessage = "Value Desc must be 1 or greater")]
    public decimal ValueDesc { get; set; }
```

...

```
@model xxxx.xxxxx.UI.Models.ModLenBinRefModelEntity

@{
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
    ViewBag.Title = "EditBin";
}
<link href="~/Content/jquery.datetimepicker.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<h2>Edit Length Bin</h2>
<h4>Station @Model.AtcId</h4>

    @using (Html.BeginForm()) 
    {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

        <div class="form-horizontal">
        <hr />

        <table class="table table-striped">
        <tr>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Bin Number")
            </th>
            <th>
                @Html.DisplayName("Value Description")
            </th>
        </tr>
        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.AtcId)    

        @for (int i=0; i<Model.LengthBinReferences.Count; i++)
        {
        <tr>
            <td>
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LengthBinReferences[i].AtcId)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LengthBinReferences[i].BinId)
                @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.LengthBinReferences[i].BinNumber)
                @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.LengthBinReferences[i].BinNumber)
            </td>
            <td>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.LengthBinReferences[i].ValueDesc)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LengthBinReferences[i].ValueDesc)
            </td>

        </tr>
        }
        </table>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Modify" class="btn btn-primary" />
                @Html.ActionLink("Cancel", "Details", new { id = Model.AtcId }, new { @class = "btn btn-default" })
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>   
}

<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.datetimepicker.full.min.js"></script
```

Comment: Its not clear what you saying here. If your seeing a validation message for one of your `ValueDesc` inputs, it means the value is NOT valid. And if you want different validation in different view, then create 2 different view models (or create a custom validation attribute that conditionally validates the value based on another property)

Comment: But your regex does not makes sense. Its a `decimal` (and you even format it it as such with one decimal place) but the regex only allows numbers, and not a decimal point. If you want to limit the values to a range, then use a `RangeAttribute`. And if you only want to allow whole numbers, then make the property `int`

Comment: Oh are you saying its firing because my regex won't allow decimal points? Ok I'll look to fix that.  My issue is that it fires for any fields I don't change the value in.

Comment: No, it fires for every field. It just displays the validation message if validation fails.